# Share plain text data from meteor.js android app using intent

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, android-intent

I have to share a link from my meteor.js app. I can't find any way to do that.

Comment: I think [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-do-share-via-using-meteor-app-apk-android/26856/5) might help you.

Comment: I want data to be shared from my app, and not to my app.